# how to use update_or_create in django createview

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I want to update_or_create object by django CreateView.
my class problem is update object but create duplicate of updated object

```
class CardexCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Cardex
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'cardex_add.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('cardexes-list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = Stock.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.object, _ = Cardex.objects.update_or_create(
            product=product, defaults={'standard_weight': 10}
        )
        return super(CardexCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```